# Swift: How to show keyboard with accessory view containing text field that becomes first responder?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview

I'm developing an iOS application in which when the user taps on a button, a function is called that shows the keyboard (without a textview or textfield initially. Only the keyboard is shown initially). The keyboard also contains a textview or textfield within its input accessory view. When the textview or textfield is tapped then the textview becomes the first responder. It would be very similar to how the Messages app on iPhones work, except the textfield/view is contained within accessory view of the same keyboard and is not visible prior. I'm struggling to visualize how this is possible - can anyone provide help?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be an input accessory view? Or you could just keep the text view/field hidden (or out of bounds of the screen) and make it visible or bring it within visible bounds on click of a button, and then make it the first responder. Then, use keyboard hide / show events to move it up on screen as you'd normally do for any other ui component.

Comment: Why do you want to open a keyboard with no textField focused? What happens when a user types?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain what you want to accomplish. This code will open the keyboard when a button is pressed and will only show the textField when the user begins typing.

When a button is pressed, we set a hidden textField's responder to true. This way, we bring up the keyboard without showing the textField. When a user begins typing, we unhide the textField and change its constraints to be above the keyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        textField.isHidden = true
        textField.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
            self.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        textField.isHidden = false
        textFieldBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
        return true
    }
}
```